# How can I avoid calling onCreate method of current activity when I press Back button

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity A that starts activity B. When I press back button in my device, the `onCreate()` method of activity B is called so I need to press back button 2 or more times to finish it. I have no idea why?!

I also tried using `onBackPressed()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` in activity B to finish it, but that didn't work!!

I really appreciate your help =)

Comment: Check your code. Sounds like you keep starting `B` somewhere

Comment: post your code...

Comment: Post the code of Activity B

Comment: Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html to understand how activities get destroyed on pressing the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); when you starting your activity B.

Comment: my pleasure...happy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Intent i = new Intent(OldActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
// clear all activities from back stack
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help =))